# php - check to see if a session file exists on server

Tags: php, session, directory, tmp

I've just encountered a problem. I store session ids in a cookie to retrieve the basket info when a user leaves a site and then comes back again. My problem being that as a test i cleared all sessions but kept the cookie but now the page just continues to load.

my question is, is there a way to firstly use php to get the tmp directory for me to then test if the session id stored is valid.

regards,

Phil

**EDIT**

i currently use

```
if( isset( $_COOKIE[$cookieKey] ) ) {
    session_id( $_COOKIE[$cookieKey] );
}
// create a new or carry on the existing session
session_start();
```

which is giving me the problem

Comment: PHP will clean up "stale" sessions every now and then, there is no reason why you should rely on checking for the presence of a particular session.

Comment: Where does `$cookieKey` come from? Are you by chance trying to share sessions between several users?

Comment: no, sharing a session over a shared SSL

Comment: How can you share SSL if HTTP is a stateless protocol?

Answer (score 1):

That's unreliable and unnecessary. Instead, add checks in your code to find out whether the `$_SESSION` superglobal is empty or (even better) has the appropriate keys:

```
<?php
if( !isset($_SESSION['foo']) ){
    // User is not fooed yet
    $_SESSION['foo'] = 33;
}
find_records_by_foo($_SESSION['foo']);
```

**Update:** No matter what you want to do with cookies and session IDs, my answer still applies. Once you're done with your cookie checks, make you session tests with `isset()`.

Answer (score 0):

I needed to do this for a different use case, basically to check if a user has a session previously active before calling `session_start()`. If anyone else ended up here like me, this is how you check if a session file exists on the server.

`session_save_path()` - get file directory where sessions are saved

`session_name()` - get name of PHP session cookie set on client (IE `PHPSESSID`)

`$_COOKIE` - PHP superglobal for cookies provided in the `Set-Cookie` HTTP header

PHP session cookies are stored with the `sess_` prefix by default.

```
print file_exists(rtrim(session_save_path(), '/') . '/sess_' . $_COOKIE[session_name()]);
```